# Bot doesn't add message member to the channel - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I'm currently working on a "temporary channels" module for my bot. When a user with a certain rank does `!newvc`, the bot creates a private voice channel that they can use, add people, and when everyone leaves, it gets automatically deleted after some time.

Everything was working fine, but I've noticed a bug that I can't find the reason behind why it happens. Basically, when you first use the command all works fine, the channel is made, you get added and it's moved to the category. But if you use it again, let's say a minute later you don't get added. The channel is made, set as private but you **message.member** doesn't get added. Then it again does and doesn't, You get the point right?

I honestly can't find a reason why it does it and the only thing I can think of is something to do with Discord's API.

Here's my code

```
        let member = message.member
        user = member.user

            message.delete()
            message.guild.createChannel(`⭐${member.user.username}'s Room`, 'voice', [{

                id: message.guild.id,
                deny: ['CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER']

            }]).then(channel => {

                channel.overwritePermissions(member, {
                    CONNECT: true,
                    USE_VAD: true,
                    PRIORITY_SPEAKER: true
                })

                channel.setParent('567718414454358026')

            })

                let privatevc = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription(':white_check_mark: Successfully created a voice channel!')
                .setColor(config.green)

                message.channel.send({ embed: privatevc }).then(msg => msg.delete(10000))
```

**FYI:** My Discord.JS version is 11.4 (didn't had time to update it, due to work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the first 2 lines should be changed to:

```js
let member = message.member,
    user = message.author;
// or
const { member, author: user } = message;
```

as whilst this isn't a problem, in strict mode it will cause an error as you technically do not have a variable keyword in front of `user = member.user`. You should try and use const if you aren't going to be changing the value of the variables. Note that `message.author` is the same as `message.member.user`.

Secondly, using the `permissionOverwrites` arg in `Guild#createChannel` is deprecated (see https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel). I am aware that Discord.JS has abolished many things despite them saying "deprecated". Try using the `typeOrOptions` argument to create the channel with the appropriate overrides instead.
Here's my suggested code:

```js
(async () => {
  message.delete();
  message.guild.createChannel(`⭐ ${message.author.username}'s Room`, {
    type: 'voice',
    parent: '567718414454358026',
    permissionOverwrites: [{
      id: message.guild.id, // @everyone has the ID of the guild
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT'],
    }, {
      id: message.author.id, // attach the permission overrides for the user directly here
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT', 'USE_VAD', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER']
    }]
  });
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription(':white_check_mark: Successfully created a voice channel!')
                .setColor(config.green);
  const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(embed);
  sentMessage.delete(10 * 1000);
})();
```

Comment: Received this error: **`TypeError: channelType.toUpperCase is not a function`**. Are you sure this works on Discord.js **11.4**?

Comment: Your code must have errors somewhere else, because none of the code sent above contains a `toUpperCase()` function call

Comment: @Tenclea But the thing is, I used it on my "test" command which is just a plain file and got the same error.

Comment: Try to search your whole code for a `channelType.toUpperCase`, and then try to fix the problem

Comment: Nothing in the code that would cause this issue. It only appeared with this code suggestion.

Comment: That's indicating that you're not using a string for your channel type. That's within the library; it'd be within the Channel options (see https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/typedef/ChannelData). For example, you might be using `{type: 1}` instead of `{type: 'voice'}` which would cause that error. The syntax in the answer should be right.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Basically, because the user was added ***after*** the channel is created, Discord API was losing it (or something, these are only my guess atm).

After changing it to this:

```
            message.guild.createChannel(`⭐${member.user.username}'s Room`, 'voice', [{

                id: message.guild.id,
                deny: ['CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER']

            }, {

                id: message.author.id,
                allow: ['CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER']

            }])
```

Everything works again. Thank you PiggyPlex.